# Density Parameter instability (Guth 1980)

Tags: cosmology

I'm reading through Guth's 1980 paper "[The Inflationary Universe](https://inspirehep.net/files/0ecbb01e927458f213e0e9362eeb16f9)" and I have one simple question (so far)...

He gives this definition of the density parameter:
\begin{equation}
.01 < \Omega_{p} < 10\tag{1.1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \Omega \equiv \frac{\rho}{\rho_{cr}} = (\frac{8\pi}{3})G\rho/H^{2}\tag{1.2}
\end{equation}

and then goes on to say,

> [...] and the subscript $p$ denotes the value at the the present time. Although these bounds do not appear at first sight to be remarkably stringent, they in fact have powerful implications. The key point is that the condition $\Omega \approx 1$ is unstable.

Is that "instability" a result of the squaring of the denominator or am I missing something more fundamental?

FWIW, my undergraduate degree was in physics, but it's been awhile and I'm trying to get back into the swing of things.

Comment: *these constraints* What constraints?

Comment: That $\rho$ is not supposed to be a subscript. I don’t see a $p$ subscript.

Comment: Edited. I put my (incorrect) notes in where I meant to put his quote.

Comment: The $\rho$ in the numerator?

Comment: Yes, the $\rho$ in the numerator that looks like it is a subscript on $G$.

Comment: *the evolving characteristic of $G$* It’s a constant. It doesn’t evolve.

Comment: Edited (again). For whatever reason I “remembered” that there was some debate about that value evolving over the course of the universe’s timeline.

Comment: Does the paragraph *after* “... is unstable” say anything about the instability?

Comment: No, at least nothing explicit. If you’re interested the original paper is here: https://inspirehep.net/files/0ecbb01e927458f213e0e9362eeb16f9

Comment: Bottom of page 3

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem) for an explanation of this “flatness problem” that Guth is alluding to.

Comment: Oh fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "instability" just refers to having $Ω_p$ approximately equal to one, which in 1980 may well have been a feasible possibility.

Regarding your mention of "squaring of the denominator", note that the critical density is defined as

$ρ_c = 3H^2/8 \pi G.$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Density_parameter